# Unable to upload apps to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm currently unable to upload apps up to iTunes. I have tried to use Xcode to to validate but this returns an error 434 but doesn't really give any information with regards to what the issue may be. I then try to use App Loader which goes through successfully and uploads but then I get an automated email from Apple with the following:

Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

I've trawled through google for the best part of today trying various fixes, recreated my provisioning profiles and I seem to have gotten nowhere. I've even gone so far as to create a brand new app and add my code in case it was a dodgy build setting but again, I still get the same result.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 8, specifically 8A218a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be put as a work around but I've managed to fix it.

On my google travels a couple of posts suggested exporting as Ad-Hoc, this is what caused the issue with application loader and Apple rejecting the binary. I've exported as iOS App Store Development and the submission went through successfully and I'm now able to select the binary in iTunes Connect.

However, this has not resolved my issue with Xcode validation and uploading so for now I'll continue to use the application loader but if anyone has any input with regards to what this issue may be, I'd appreciate it.